# Trouble Displaying Canvas in Basic HTML Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a basic HTML game using the Canvas element, but I am having trouble with it. Unfortunately, I don't know where the error is in my code, so I have posted the entirety of the document I'm working on below.

My problem: The canvas is not displaying when I run the HTML document.

This code's based off of (as in it pretty much is) the Movement tutorial from w3schools for using the Canvas, available at https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_movement_keyboard, but when chaing variable names I must've broken something, because after looking at this for hours I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
  canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body onload = "initial()">

<script>
var playerOne;

function initial() {
  playerOne = new canvasObject(30, 30, "red", 225, 225);
  gameArea.start();
}

var gameArea = {
  canvas : document.createElement("canvas");
  start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
        gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
  },
  stop : function() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
  },    
  clear : function() {
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function canvasObject(width, height, color, x, y, type)
{
 this.type = type;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speed = 0;
  this.angle = 0;
  this.moveAngle = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = gameArea.context;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.restore();    
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
   this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
    this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
    this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  gameArea.clear();
  playerOne.moveAngle = 0;
  playerOne.speed = 0;
  if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[37]) {
   playerOne.moveAngle = -1; 
  }
  if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[39]) {
   playerOne.moveAngle = 1; 
   
  }
  if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[38]) {
   playerOne.speed= 1; 
   
  }
  if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[40]) {
   playerOne.speed= -1; 
   
  }
  playerOne.newPos();
  playerOne.update();
}

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gameArea` is an object. Object properties are separated with `,`, not `;`. Hence, there is a syntax error after the definition of `canvas`.

```js
var playerOne;

function initial() {
  playerOne = new canvasObject(30, 30, "red", 225, 225);
  gameArea.start();
}

var gameArea = {
  canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
  start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
        gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
  },
  stop : function() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
  },    
  clear : function() {
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function canvasObject(width, height, color, x, y, type)
{
 this.type = type;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speed = 0;
  this.angle = 0;
  this.moveAngle = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = gameArea.context;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.restore();    
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
   this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
    this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
    this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  gameArea.clear();
  playerOne.moveAngle = 0;
  playerOne.speed = 0;
  if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[37]) {
   playerOne.moveAngle = -1; 
  }
  if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[39]) {
   playerOne.moveAngle = 1; 
   
  }
  if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[38]) {
   playerOne.speed= 1; 
   
  }
  if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[40]) {
   playerOne.speed= -1; 
   
  }
  playerOne.newPos();
  playerOne.update();
}
```

```css
  canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
```

```html
<body onload = "initial()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
var gameArea = {
  canvas : document.createElement("canvas");
  ...
}
```

You've used `;` instead of `,`